# Deserialization of formerly classes Implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, deserialization, inotifypropertychanged

I had some problems with `serialization` of my classes implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` events. ([Binary Serialization of ViewModel (ObservableCollection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304658/binary-serialization-of-viewmodel-observablecollection))

Solved as recommended in [SerializationException when serializing instance of a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879426/serializationexception-when-serializing-instance-of-a-class-which-implements-ino)

Now I have a problem with the `deserialization`. When doing it like

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();            
        FileStream fs_open = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\vm_user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\testbin.txt", FileMode.Open);
        ViewModels.MainViewModel mvm1 = (ViewModels.MainViewModel)formatter.Deserialize(fs_open);
        fs_open.Close();
```

The `deserialized` objects do not fire any `events` anymore.

**What do I have to do to get the same functionality as before the serialization?** Right now I do it with this:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        ViewModels.MainViewModel mvm1 = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
        FileStream fs_open = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\vm_user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\testbin.txt", FileMode.Open);            
        foreach (ViewModels.WatchedFile file in ( (ViewModels.MainViewModel)formatter.Deserialize(fs_open) ).WatchedFiles)
        {
            ViewModels.WatchedFile wf = new ViewModels.WatchedFile(file.Name, file.Path, file.Tags, new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.WatchedFile>());
            foreach (ViewModels.WatchedFile subs in file.Subs)
            {
                wf.Subs.Add(refeshLoadedFiles(subs));
            }
            mvm1.WatchedFiles.Add(wf);
        }
        fs_open.Close();
```

and refreshLoadedFiles:

```
 private ViewModels.WatchedFile refeshLoadedFiles( ViewModels.WatchedFile fileSource)
    {
        ViewModels.WatchedFile wf = new ViewModels.WatchedFile(fileSource.Name, fileSource.Path, fileSource.Tags, new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.WatchedFile>());
        foreach (ViewModels.WatchedFile subs in fileSource.Subs)
        {
            wf.Subs.Add(refeshLoadedFiles(subs));
        }            
        return wf;
    }
```

But this can´t be the goal of `serialization`, can it? Beacause if I do it this way I can write my information into any textfile with simple text stating the `type` and then all the rest...

Thanks for your help.

This is the ViewModel (edit):

```
namespace WatchedFile.ViewModels
{
[Serializable()]
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}

[Serializable()]
public class WatchedFile : ViewModelBase
{
#region Name Property
private String _name = default(String);
public String Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _name)
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
#endregion Name Property

#region Path Property
private String _path = default(String);
public String Path
{
    get { return _path; }
    set
    {
        setDisplayImage(value);
        if (value != _path)
        {
            _path = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
}
#endregion Path Property

#region Tags Property
private ObservableCollection<Tag> _tags = new ObservableCollection<Tag>();
public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags
{
    get { return _tags; }
    protected set
    {
        if (value != _tags)
        {
            _tags = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
#endregion Tags Property

#region Subs Property
private ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> _subs = new ObservableCollection<WatchedFile>();
public ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> Subs
{
    get { return _subs; }
    protected set
    {
        setDisplayImage(Path);
        if (value != _subs)
        {
            _subs = value;
            _subs.CollectionChanged += _subs_CollectionChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void _subs_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Subs = Sort(Subs);
}
#endregion Subs Property

[NonSerialized()]
private BitmapImage _displayImage = default(BitmapImage);
public BitmapImage DisplayImage
{
    get { return _displayImage; }
    protected set
    {
        if (value != _displayImage)
        {
            _displayImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public WatchedFile(): this(string.Empty,string.Empty,new ObservableCollection<Tag>(),new ObservableCollection<WatchedFile>())
{                                    
}

public WatchedFile(String name, String path, ObservableCollection<Tag> tags, ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> subitems)
{
    Subs = WatchedFile.Sort(subitems);
    Name = name;
    Path = path;
    Tags = tags;
}

public static ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> Sort(ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> files)
{
    if (files == null)
        return files;
    ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> filesReturn = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.WatchedFile>();
    WatchedFile[] sortedArray = files.ToArray();

    WatchedFile temp;
    for (int j = 1; j <= sortedArray.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = j; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (sortedArray[i].Subs != null && sortedArray[i].Subs.Count > 1)
            {
                ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> subs = Sort(sortedArray[i].Subs);
                sortedArray[i].Subs.Clear();
                foreach (WatchedFile f in subs)
                    sortedArray[i].Subs.Add(f);
            }

            if (sortedArray[i - 1].Subs != null && sortedArray[i - 1].Subs.Count > 1)
            {
                ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> subs = Sort(sortedArray[i - 1].Subs);
                sortedArray[i - 1].Subs.Clear();
                foreach (WatchedFile f in subs)
                    sortedArray[i - 1].Subs.Add(f);
            }

            if (( sortedArray[i].Name ).CompareTo(sortedArray[i - 1].Name) == -1)
            {
                temp = sortedArray[i];
                sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[i - 1];
                sortedArray[i - 1] = temp;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    filesReturn.Clear();
    foreach (WatchedFile f in sortedArray)
        filesReturn.Add(f);

    return filesReturn;
}
}

[Serializable()]
public class Tag
{
public Tag(String value)
{
    Value = value;
}
public String Value { get; private set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
public MainViewModel()
{

}

#region WatchedFiles Property        
private ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> _watchedFiles = new ObservableCollection<WatchedFile>();
public ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> WatchedFiles
{
    get { return _watchedFiles; }
    protected set
    {
        if (value != _watchedFiles)
        {
            _watchedFiles =WatchedFile.Sort(value);// value;
            _watchedFiles.CollectionChanged += _watchedFiles_CollectionChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void _watchedFiles_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WatchedFiles = WatchedFile.Sort(WatchedFiles);
}
#endregion WatchedFiles Property
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They don't fire because nothing is subscribed to them. In WPF, the framework will subscribe during binding in the background when the view or control is loaded. Since you're doing this at a different stage in the pipeline, you're going to have to figure out a better way to load the model at the right stage so that the subscriptions occur again. Hard to say without seeing more, but this is very smelly. Is this a control or the full view's datacontext?

At the very least, force a rebind of the model. Otherwise, maybe serialize a dto instead and inject into the viewmodel and use it to restore state before loading the view, or give the main view model a method that takes the dto and rebinds it to an observable property. Like I said, it's hard to say without seeing what you're really doing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DTO option.  Reworking this system to use a DTO for the serialization will prevent a lot of headaches at the cost of just a little bit of glue code.

Comment: can you explain what a `DTO` is?  (add a link or something?) and shouldn´t it at least do/use the set accessors when changing something? (added the `ViewModel` to the question) the `ViewModel` is Bound to a `TreeView`

Comment: The point of a view model is to back a view, dto is primarily for transporting state. A DTO is just a property bag; an object with a bunch of properties and no behavior. I often use these for situations like this where the object whose state you're trying to restore has encapsulated behavior that you generally don't want to open up to external sources. So in this case you'd use the DTO to sort of restore the data to the VM. Pass it the DTO containing all of the state info and allow the VM to restore its own state and enforce any rules, like the rebinding of observables to controls on the view

Comment: This way, the main VM is statically bound; it'll always be there and objects will always be subscribed at the correct point in time. So then updating it from some data stored in a database is as simply as feeding the VM (or a property on the vm) something more data like `ExistingProperty = new ObservableCollection(myDto);` or whatever is more appropriate for your situation. Since the VM never actually changed, all subscribers of INotifyPropertyChanged will still be notified of any changes