# c# serialization creates an empty file

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to develop a library app in c# but I am stuck in the serialization of an ObservableCollection class.

The feature test is :

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void saveFile_createTheFile()
        {

            var btn_saveFile = createA<WpfButton>("btn_saveToFile");
            if (fileManager.saveFileExists())
                return;

            btn_saveFile.Click();

            fileManager.saveFileExists().ShouldBeTrue();

        }
```

I think it is auto-documented, easy to understand.
I am faced to 2 problems:
- after the test, a save file is created but the test failure message tells me that the saveFileExists() method returns false.
- the save file is created in the right directory, but it is an empty file, I don't know why.

here is my tool class dedicated to the file management:

```
public class FileManager
    {
        private string SAVEFILE = "datas.saved";
        public string appDir = null;
        public string pathToSaveFile = null;

        public FileManager()
        {
            appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            pathToSaveFile = Path.Combine(appDir, SAVEFILE);
        }

        public Boolean saveFileExists()
        {
            return File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + SAVEFILE);

        }

        public void saveToFile(ObservableCollection<Book> books)
        {

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(SAVEFILE, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, books.ToArray());
            stream.Close();

        }

    }
```

can someone tell me why I get these two errors?

thank you

ps : At startup, the collection contains 2 books.The Book class is serializable.

EDIT

I found the reason : by debugging, I got this error : at the "formatter.Serialize(...)" method, there is the error "PropertyChangeEventManager is not serializable". Indeed, here is the Book class:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string _title;

        public string title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("title");
            }
        }


        public string _author;

        public string author
        {
            get { return _author; }
            set
            {
                _author = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("author");
            }
        }


        public string _editor;

        public string editor
        {
            get { return _editor; }
            set
            {
                _editor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("editor");
            }
        }


        public string _isbn;

        public string ISBN
        {
            get { return _isbn; }
            set
            {
                _isbn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ISBN");
            }
        }

        public DateTime _bookAdded;

        public DateTime bookAdded
        {
            get { return _bookAdded; }
            set
            {
                _bookAdded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("bookAdded");
            }
        }

        public Book(string isbn,string title,string author,string editor, DateTime bookAdded)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.ISBN = isbn;
            this.author = author;
            this.editor = editor;
            this.bookAdded = bookAdded;

        }

        public Book()
        {
            bookAdded=DateTime.Today;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

this is a subclass and the base class has surely added some non serializable fields. How can I avoid this? I am rather a newbie to wpf but I think the notifications are mandatory in Book in order to tell to the window's binded components that a change has been done.

Comment: Does the file exist in the directory as specified by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? (In other words, do you _really_ know what `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is when you run the test?) Note that the path of the save file in `pathToSaveFile` does not use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to determine the directory for the file, but rather the executing assembly location. The `saveFileExists` method does not use _pathToSaveFile_, but composes the path to the file again using a different approach with the "current directory". (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Creating the path for the save file in entirely different ways does not instill confidence in me that the result will always be the same path. Why does _saveFileExists()_  not use `pathToSaveFile`?

Comment: Side note: Don't do a manual close on a FileStream. If the serializer for whatever reason throws a tantrum and an exception, the close method will not be invoked, keeping the file open and locked until either the GC finalizes the FileStream object (which could take ages...) or your program ends (whatever coming first). Rather, encapsulate your FileStream object in a `using` statement, and drop the "manual" Close() call...

Comment: The only place in the code posted that saves the file is the method saveToFile().  You are never calling the method any place in the posted code.

Comment: @jdweng : there is a button which action is to call saveToFile.

Comment: @elgonzo : you have right, for the use of using and for the doubled means of accessing to the file. I have already noticed this, and now I am using pathToFile in saveFileExists. plz have a look at my edit!

Comment: You don't want the event to get serialized, apply the [NonSerializable] attribute to it.  It is highly recommended to keep the data declaration separate, this still needs to work n+1 years from now after you've had a lot of reasons to change the Book class but you need to deserialize old data.

Comment: I tried to apply the [NonSerializable] attribute to the event but it was replied that only fields can be decorated with such an attribute. moreover, the error I mentioned concerned an other, inherited, field. I still don't know how to progress except avoiding the forementioned inheritance, which could cause gui errors

Comment: ok, done : have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879426/serializationexception-when-serializing-instance-of-a-class-which-implements-ino

Comment: The button method saveFile_createTheFile is NOT saving the file nor calling the method saveToFile().